# Finding Alternatives to Figma

Tags: design

Now that Figma has decided to charge developers, I wonder if there are alternative programs in the market that my team and I can switch over. It doesn't have to be as fancy as Figma, as long as it can provide basic CSS properties, sizing, and padding between the components. We are looking for basic designer and developer handoffs.

Is there something similar to Figma available in the market? Or do we just have to accept and pay more?

[image: Figma Banner]
[image: Sizing]
[image: Margin between components]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please add what OS(es)/programming language(s) should be supported? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Mac and Windows, and I only want CSS properties. If it supports react/react native that would be amazing, but its not a deal break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Penpot](https://penpot.app/) is the first open-source design & prototyping tool for product teams, that allows full collaboration between designers and developers thanks to features such as Flex Layout and Code Inspect.

[Pencil Project](https://pencil.evolus.vn/) is a standalone app that lets you create diagrams or UI mockups. It doesn't have collaboration/multi-user features.

[Lunacy](https://icons8.com/lunacy) is a native Windows app that opens, edits, and stores .sketch files. In short, it’s long-awaited Sketch for Windows. It solves the big pain of design teams working on different operating systems and improves the process of transition from design to development.

There are many more alternatives you can find [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/figma/). I hope my answer helped you!

Comment: Penpot looks very similar to Figma. Thank you for this!